# VBA Save file from web url without file name

Tags: excel, vba

I have attempted quite a few variations however this i believe is the closest i have gotten to having it working and I simply do not know how to proceed.

Here is the basic concept.
I have a url that will trigger the creation and the download of an XLS formatted file.
My code gets all the way to opening this file with the use of sendkeys(%a accepts the security warning (would like to skip if there is a way, at this point i need to basically make sure that the opened file from download is the active window before proceeding. keep in mind the downloaded filename can vary slightly.

There is still some garbage from other things i was attempting.

Question: How can I do a loop until, or if, etc  to insure that the active window is either MyBrowser(IE) or the Excel workbook i just opened with the send keys?

```
Sub SearchRepQ()

    Dim USER1 As String
        'USER1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("SRC").Range("D:D"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(UserForm1("TextBox1"), Sheets("SRC").Range("C:C"), 0))
    Dim prefix1 As String
    Dim prefix2 As String
        prefix1 = "https://MyReports.com/default.aspx?&sk=Mgmt+Console&s=~_d0!2!1!!1!7!0!1!!2!!!0!1!3!2!_d2!"
        prefix2 = "!Central+Standard+Time!_d6!fvf%7c%40ticketowner!DrurxrErsrzqFqypvspwpxpCpvtpwpwpqBqypvspwpxpApvtpwpwpqqrzqqqrur!fvf%7c%40ticketstatusopenclosed!_d0!4!Mgmt+Console!Open!_d1!_d8!!yqHqtFpGpxpvppupxpupvpupwppwpppupvpKpJpIpEpzpBpApCppDpqyprpqsq!&xls=h$Mgmt_32_Console$ctl00$mup$t$ctl00$ctl00$exl"
    Dim MyURL1 As String
    Dim MyURL2 As String
        MyURL1 = ("https://MyReports.com")
        MyURL2 = (prefix1 & USER1 & prefix2)

    Dim MyBrowser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    Dim XL As Excel.Application
    'Dim IEe As New IEEvents
    Set XL = Excel.Application
    'Set IEe.IEApp = MyBrowser
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MyURL1
    Do Until MyBrowser.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    MyBrowser.navigate MyURL2
    Do Until MyBrowser.READYSTATE = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    VBA.AppActivate MyBrowser.document.Title & " - " & MyBrowser.Name, 0
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
         SendKeys "%(o)"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
         SendKeys "%(a)"

    'Dim counter As Integer
    '    Set counter = 0
    'Dim number As Integer = 8
    'Do Until number = 10
    '    If number <= 0 Then Exit Do
    '    number -= 1
    '    counter += 1
    'Loop
    VBA.AppActivate XL.ActiveWindow.Activate.Title("coveo*", 0)
end sub
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Can you not just use the url to direct binary/urlMon download?

Comment: updated with my specific question.

Comment: Why is there the possibility that another window is active (an not MyBrowser(IE)  or Excel)?

Comment: You might want to use a tool for window automation to control the active window (and react in the desired manner): https://www.autoitscript.com/ or https://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: see also https://blog.testproject.io/2016/12/22/open-source-test-automation-tools-for-desktop-applications/

Comment: There is a new windows, because my script so far has launched ie and triggered a URL that downloads a file and then send keys that open the file... the next step would be to do a save as in the new excel window.

I have gone this route, because all other methods i have attempted to use to trigger the file download and save it have failed. This include those scripts that call for API. everything i find online for doing what i am trying to do is either way old and doesn't work, because my url does not include an actual file name.

Comment: To be clear urlmon doesn't work, because my link does not have a file name. the link triggers what i believe is a jscipt on the web page that then generates the file and then i get the file download dialog.

Comment: API has not worked because no one seems to have a solution for the security dialog, at least that i have found. 
So I am resorting to send keys.  %o to open then i need to %a for the security dialog, then i need to wait/insure the window is the opened file before continuing. 
At  least that is what I am currently attempting, unless someone has a better solution.